# DTrace objc : invalid probe specifier : "$1 is not referenced"

Tags: dtrace

For some reason, which I need to determine, in my macOS app, when the Save panel appears for the first time in a newly-duplicated document, macOS is deleting the temporarily auto-saved document file, which of course causes the later save to fail.  Here is a DTrace transcript, which I have abridged somewhat:

```
Air2 jk$ sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::unlink*:entry { printf("time=%d  execname=%s  arg=%s\n", timestamp/1000000000, execname, copyinstr(arg0)); ustack(100); }' -p `pgrep MyApp`
Password:
dtrace: description 'syscall::unlink*:entry' matched 4 probes
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
  1    178                     unlink:entry time=6562  execname=com.apple.appkit  arg=/Users/jk/Library/Autosave Information/Unsaved MyApp Document.bmco

              libsystem_kernel.dylib`__unlink+0xa
              libremovefile.dylib`__removefile_tree_walker+0x147
              libremovefile.dylib`removefile+0x99
              Foundation`-[NSFilesystemItemRemoveOperation main]+0xba
              Foundation`__NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__+0x11
              Foundation`-[NSOperation start]+0x2db
              Foundation`-[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:]+0x54
              AppKit`__90-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsFromRecords:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke_2+0x90
              AppKit`__89-[NSDocumentController reopenDocumentForURL:withContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2+0xa6
              AppKit`___NSMainRunLoopPerformBlockInModes_block_invoke+0x19
              CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__+0xc
              CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks+0x17b
              CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun+0xae8
              CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific+0x1f3
              HIToolbox`RunCurrentEventLoopInMode+0x124
              HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon+0x164
              HIToolbox`_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter+0x40
              AppKit`_DPSNextEvent+0x3de
              AppKit`-[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]+0x548
              ViewBridge`-[NSViewServiceApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]+0x5f
              AppKit`-[NSApplication run]+0x292
              AppKit`NSApplicationMain+0x309
              libxpc.dylib`_xpc_objc_main.cold.3+0x38
              libxpc.dylib`_xpc_objc_main+0x203
              libxpc.dylib`_xpc_copy_xpcservice_dictionary
              ViewBridge`xpc_connection_handler
              ViewBridge`NSViewServiceApplicationMain+0xbff
              com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService`main+0xc0
              libdyld.dylib`start+0x1
              com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService`0x1
```

> 

The above result tells me that

(1) it is not my process but a process named `com.apple.appkit`, or maybe `com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService`, which is ultimately calling `unlink`, and

(2) this occurs while executing an Objective-C block within `-[NSDocumentController reopenDocumentForURL:withContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:]`.

I think the latter is a clue to the problem, since there should be nothing to reopen.  So I want to find out what is calling `-[NSDocumentController reopenDocumentForURL:withContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:]`.  The above result does not tell that because this is a block invocation.

So I tried to craft another DTrace command, with an Objective-C probe which will trigger whenever this appkit process calls `-[NSDocumentController reopenDocumentForURL:withContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:]`:

```
sudo dtrace -n 'objc$target:NSDocumentController:-reopenDocumentForURL?withContentsOfURL?display?completionHandler?:entry { printf("time=%d  arg=%s\n", timestamp/1000000000, copyinstr(arg0)); ustack(100); }' -p `pgrep appkit`
dtrace: invalid probe specifier objc$target:NSDocumentController:-reopenDocumentForURL?withContentsOfURL?display?completionHandler?:entry { printf("time=%d  arg=%s\n", timestamp/1000000000, copyinstr(arg0)); ustack(100); }: extraneous argument '7135' ($1 is not referenced)
```

> 

But as you can see, it complains of *invalid probe specifier* and *$1 is not referenced*.  The `-p` is apparently working because 7135 indeed is the pid of the com.apple.appkit process running on my Mac.  I presume this is the *$1* which is referred to, and for some reason the *$target* is not *referencing* it as expected.

So, instead I specified the pid literally (*objc7135*), and that worked, (*matched 1 probe*), but it does not catch the desired call, probably because the call is being done by a *second* running instance of process `com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService` which starts up whenever a save or autosave occurs, and of course an autosave happens whenever I switch apps to Terminal to run `ps` and make a new probe.  So the call has already occurred before I can set a probe to it.  Arghhhh!!!

If I could get above DTrace command to work, I think it would attach to the newly-started appkit process and give the answer I want.  Why does my DTrace command give that error?

UPDATE 2019-AUG-07:

Well, I determined that the cause I was looking for is in fact a reproducible bug in macOS AppKit, so I have submitted a nice new Feedback and am praying that Apple fixes it.  But I still think my question here is a good DTrace question, and would be happy to accept a correct answer :)

UPDATE 2019-AUG-09:

I tried suggestion by @ahl at transposit.com.  Realizing that nested DTrace calls would be backslash escape hell, I put my original DTrace call in a named DTraceMe.sh, and ran this:

```
sudo dtrace -wn 'proc:::exec-success { if (execname == "com.apple.appkit") { printf("Launched: %s pid=%d\n", execname, pid); system("~/Desktop/Temp/DTraceMe.sh"); }}'
```

This fixes the error message and runs `DTraceMe.sh` when my app shows the troublesome Save panel.  Nice!  But unfortunately, as usual, the inner DTrace instance apparently takes several seconds to install its probes (and print *dtrace: blahblah matched 1 probe*).  So by the time it is armed, the troublesome call to NSDocumentController which I am trying to trace is already done and gone.

Well, I thought, maybe I could stop the newly-launched com.apple.appkit process long enough for DTrace to get going by running a lldb instance which would attach to the next com.apple.appkit which launched:

```
(lldb) process attach --name com.apple.appkit --waitfor
```

To my surprise, that actually did break and stop the target com.apple.appkit process immediately after it launched.  (Of course I have disabled System Integrity Protection.)  But now the inner DTrace instance immediately tells me that my probe specifier *does not match any probes*, presumably because com.apple.appkit cannot cooperate with DTrace while it is stopped by lldb.  Sad.

Comment: Once you've got lldb attached to the target process, you don't need to use DTrace to find the Objective-C call you're interested in. You can just use a breakpoint. As to the race trying to use DTrace on a newly-exec'd process, you can call `stop()` to suspend it. Your `DTraceMe.sh` script could use `pidresume()` on the target in a `BEGIN` probe to resume it. (`pidresume()` is a Mac-specific extension and is documented in the `dtrace` man page.)

Answer (score 4):

It seems likely that `pgrep appkit` is returning multiple pids which would explain the `$1 is not referenced` error.

Tracing newly created processes can be tricky depending on what you're trying to do exactly. In this case, I'd suggest you trace the `proc:::exec-success` probe and from there use the `system()` action to fire off *another* instance of the dtrace command that traces that newly created process.

Comment: Thank you, @ahl.  See the UPDATE 2019-AUG-09 in my question.

Comment: When you have a freshly created process it may not yet have libraries loaded. Try adding the `-Z` option to the dtrace command. This ignores the "zero probes matched" failure *and* when new libraries show up, DTrace should try to instrument them.

Answer (score 1):

I like the brute-force method.  This will catch all `unlink` calls (unless something is cleaning out a lot of files, file unlinks are actually pretty rare):

```
dtrace -n 'syscall::unlink*:entry { printf("time=%d arg=%s\n",
    timestamp/1000000000, copyinstr(arg0)); ustack(100); }'
```

Save the output to a file and go through it.

Or, if you know the name of the executable, add something like an `/ execname == "com.apple.appkit" /` predicate to limit the probe to only those events that match the predicate:

```
dtrace -n 'syscall::unlink*:entry / execname == "com.apple.appkit" /
    { printf("time=%d arg=%s\n", timestamp/1000000000, copyinstr(arg0)); ustack(100); }'
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrew, but I already did that and have the call stack which is calling `unlink`.  It is being called by an Objective-C block within --[NSDocumentController:reopenDocumentForURL:withContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:].  So I need to know what is calling *that*, for which I need to use DTrace' *objc* provider.  Although the *syscall* provider triggers on calls from any process by default, as I understand it, the *objc* provider only installs probes in a given process.  That is the quandary.